# How to automatically start a RubyOnRails app on server startup" (hopefully with more details about environment and nginx logs)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, puma

I am having troubles with auto-scaling group in AWS. I am running a Ruby on Rails App in EC2 instance with ELB. I applied auto-scaling group so it scales-up automatically when heavy traffics come. However, the app server upon nginx does not start automatically so it becomes "OutOfService" in ELB. Any solution?

Comment: Seems like your question has little to do wth AWS, and that it should be stated as "How to automatically start a RubyOnRails app on server startup" (hopefully with more details about environment and nginx logs)?

Comment: @DusanBajic I updated it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can either use Monit to monitor your services, in this case Nginx and/or ( Puma, Unicorn, Passenger etc.. ) or use unix's own 'service' for things like this, Upstart.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-linux-service-to-start-automatically-after-a-crash-or-reboot-part-1-practical-examples#auto-starting-services-with-upstart